# how to read file request with pymodbus

Tags: python, pymodbus3

Actually I'm working with modbus protocol, and I need make a program using pymodbus library however I don't know many things about this protocol. I know to do basic somethings, for example: read input/holding registers but I need read the waveforms. In the device's docs says that I have to write the Read-File request for file 128 and then read the data from the file response block, but I don't know how. How to write the Read-File request with pymodbus? I need to use write_register()? I hope you can help me and sorry for my english